# scrapy python why is the location header value not getting assigned

Tags: python, scrapy

```
 def parse_url(self, response):
     item = response.meta['item']
     if response.status in [301, 302, 303, 307] and 'Location' in response.headers:
         item['url']  = response.headers['location']
         print item['url']
     else:
         item['url'] = ""
     return item
```

In this case i am passing a list named "item" from another function. i need to set a value of the header. but it is not getting set? please help

Comment: is it Location or location???

Comment: tried both with no lock

Comment: what does the print give ?? on line number 5 here??

Comment: Check the logs. I'm pretty sure the Scrapy redirect middleware is grabbing the 302 response before it even gets to the spider, so you never actually see these responses, only the redirected ones.

Comment: is there a way to get the location header in that case? i want to extract the value

Comment: You can disable `RedirectMiddleware` with [`REDIRECT_ENABLED=False`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:setting-REDIRECT_ENABLED)

Answer (score 0):

In the method that generates this request, set the `dont_redirect` meta key (to anything). The redirect middleware will pass the response as-is to the spider and won't handle redirects:

```
request.meta['dont_redirect'] = True
```